# Moment Generating Function Given Expectations

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

How would I go about finding the moment generating function given the expectations? For example, given $E(X^n)=n!$ for $n \in Z_+$, what is the moment generating function of X? In this case the random variable is discrete, but I would also like to apply to a similar case of a continuous random variable.

I feel like I should be able to use the fact that $E(X^n)=\frac{d^nM_X(t=0)}{d^nt}=n!$, but I feel like it just turns into a computational nightmare very quickly.

Comment: $$M_X(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{E(X^n)}{n!}t^n$$

Comment: How did you (or anyone) derive the formula? Can you explain what it means?

Comment: This is simply the expansion $$e^{tx}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}t^n$$ together with the definition $$M_X(t)=E(e^{tX})$$